# Programming a temperature sensor in python

Tags: python, sensors, temperature

I'm trying to make code for my temperature sensor. Been stuck on a `NameError` when I try to execute the code. My question is, does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
import datetime
from sense_hat import SenseHat

def hotwater():
    sense = SenseHat()
    sense.clear()
    celcius = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)

result = 'temp. C' + str(celcius)
print(result)
result_list = [(datetime.datetime.now(), celcius)]

while __name__ == '__main__':
    Hotwater()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    file "/home/pi/Web_test.py", line 9 in <module>
       results= 'temp. C' + str(celcius)
NameError: name 'celcius' is not defined
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'celcius' is not defined` means just what it says ... `celcius` is not defined at the point where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The variable Celsius is only accessible in the hotwater function. It cannot be accessed outside of it. To fix the issue, you could move the printing into the hotwater function:

```
def hotwater():
    sense = SenseHat()
    sense.clear()
    celcius = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
    result = 'temp. C' + str(celcius)
    print(result)
    result_list = [(datetime.datetime.now(), celcius)]

hotwater()
```

Or, you could have hotwater return celsius:

```
def hotwater():
    sense = SenseHat()
    sense.clear()
    celcius = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
    return celcius

celcius= hotwater()
result = 'temp. C' + str(celcius)
print(result)
result_list = [(datetime.datetime.now(), celcius)]
```

Although you could use the global keyword to make celsius accessible everywhere, that is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Your function fails to returned the value to the main program.
Variable `celcius`[sic] is local to the function.
Also, you've failed to invoke the function where you try to use the value.

Follow the examples in your learning materials: call the function, return the value to the main program, and save or use it as needed:

```
def hotwater():
    sense = SenseHat()
    sense.clear()
    return round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        celsius = hotwater()
        result = 'temp. C' + str(celcius)
        print(result)
        result_list = [(datetime.datetime.now(), celcius)]
```

I'm not sure what plans you have for `result_list`, but I think you'll need to update the code above.